# Setup LinkedIn account with two-step authentication in Mac OS X?

Tags: contacts

How do I setup a LinkedIn account on my Mac OS X Mavericks when I enable two-step authentication within LinkedIn?

Answer (score 1):

The LinkedIn help site have the following section, that also applies to Mac OS X LinkedIn integration:

> Some partner applications will simply show an invalid email or
>   password message when you try to sign in for the first time. If you're
>   signing in to one of these applications after turning on two-step
>   verification:
>
> Check your SMS on your mobile device after your first attempt to sign
>   in, to get the verification code. Sign in again using your password
>   followed by the verification code (with no space in between) that was
>   sent to your mobile device.
>
> Source: http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/559/kw/2%20step%20verification